# Add and new column/attribute to sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to add a new column to a model that has already been defined?

Something like:

```
var Agency = sequelize.define("agency", {
  agency_id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    primaryKey: true
  },
  agency_name: DataTypes.STRING(255),
  agency_url: DataTypes.STRING(255)
});

Agency.addColumn({ agency_lang: DataTypes.STRING(2) });
```

Answer (score 0):

**theoretically** you could do `Agency.rawAttributes.agency_lang =...` and then call `Agency.refreshAttributes`. However, there is no guarantee that this will work in all cases, since `refreshAttributes` is not part of the public API.

Why do you need to alter the attributes after the model has been defined? Sequelize does not support automagically altering the table, so you'd need to `DROP TABLE + CREATE TABLE` to reflect the new structure in the DB

Comment: When I am populating a table, in some cases I want to add a column.  In this specific case, I plan on adding a geometry column using PostGIS.

Comment: But you do realize that you will still have to create the `ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN` manually, right? (or call `addColumn`, but simply adding it to the model definiton is not enough)

Comment: Just tried that, and I got an error.  I ended up overwriting the existing one with an alternate model definition.